# hub: uncaught exception -> KeyError: <ryu.topology.switches.Port object at >

Tags: mininet, sdn, ryu

I have made a controller using Ryu which handles the paths and switches. The code seems to be working but I receive the following error. It is asynchronous meaning it does't seem to be related to any event and happens every once in a while. The thing is that those files are the Ryu files and I have not changed them.

I am using mininet to virtualize the network.

```
hub: uncaught exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/lib/hub.py", line 52, in _launch
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/topology/switches.py", line 821, in link_loop
    self.links.link_down(link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/topology/switches.py", line 329, in link_down
    del self._map[link.src]
KeyError: <ryu.topology.switches.Port object at 0x7f92d4c5df10>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Files:

- [switches.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/topology/switches.py)
- [hub.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/lib/hub.py)

Comment: Can you link those files?

Comment: Added the link in the main question.